# PHPのタイムゾーン設定が反映されない

Tags: php, xampp

Xampp 最新版の 5.6.21 をインストールしました。
タイムゾーンを `Asia/Tokyo` に変更したいのですが、うまくいきません。

`phpinfo()` を見ると、

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File   C:\{...}\xampp\php\php.ini
```

となっているので、この `php.ini` の941行目付近を以下のように変更しました。

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone ="Asia/Tokyo"
; ("Asia/Tokyo"ではなくAsia/Tokyoでも試しましたが駄目でした)
```

しかし、`phpinfo()` の date のデフォルトはドイツのままです。

どうすればいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score -1, accepted):

php.ini内にdate.timezoneの記述場所が２箇所あります。
探してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

XAMPPを再起動はされましたか？
されていなければ一度お試しを…

Comment: xamppも再起動しましたが、駄目でした。

Comment: ダブルクォートを付けたままでしょうか？

date.timezone = Asia/Tokyo 
ダブルクォートを外して保存をしてXAMPPを再起動してみてください。
php.iniはあまり触らないのですが…
それくらいしか触った記憶がありません…

Comment: 自分の環境を確認したら、ダブルクォートで囲っていました。

MAMPなのですが、パスは
bin/php/php7.0.0/conf/php.ini
でした。
内容は、Hambrianさんの記述していた通りです。

php.iniのファイルが複数ある場合もあるそうです。
私も違う階層にphp.iniファイルを見つけました。
Hambrianさんも他のディレクトリに無いか確認してみてください。

最悪…解決にはなりませんが、phpファイル内に記述することでも対応出来ます。

PHPマニュアル
http://php.net/manual/ja/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

<?php
// タイムゾーンを指定
print "default : ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."<br>";
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo'); 
print "Tokyo : ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."<br>";
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
print "Los : ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>

力不足な回答で申し訳ないです。